# How to remove decimal sign from number but preserve all digits?

Tags: javascript

How to convert this `20,00` into `2000` in javascript ?
Basically how to remove decimal sign but keep all digits?

Comment: 20,00 is not a Number and  comma is not a decimal-sign in javascript.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: nobody said it's supposed to be a number in JS, right? Although `,` is a decimal separator in some locales, it's not really relevant - this is for all intents and porpoises a manipulation on strings, functionally equivalent to `XX-zz` -> `XXzz`.

Comment: I guess the title/tag  said it: **How to remove decimal sign from number** , tagged as **javascript**

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Oh. Didn't notice the title. You're right of course, `20,00` is not a number literal in JS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everybody stand back[,](http://xkcd.com/208/) I know regular expressions!

```
var originalstring = '20,00';
var newstring = originalstring.replace(/,/g, '');
```

In other words, [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) all occurences of `,` with an empty string. You could even use a character class to remove anything *except* digits, if that's your intention:

```
var originalstring = '20,00';
var newstring = originalstring.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

That may be useful as the decimal delimiter is locale-specific (which e.g. means that in English (`en_US`), "two and a half" is "2.5", whereas in Czech (`cs_CZ`) it's "2,5"). Although JS always uses the decimal *point* for numbers, user-entered data will depend on the locale (e.g. the key next to 0 on numpad emits a `,` in some layouts), which can lead to confusion if your script expects a decimal comma and gets a decimal point instead.

Comment: How would you proceed backwards? Eg. 2000 > 20,00

Comment: @arma: Unless you know how many decimal places you're supposed to have (two?), you can't (Was it 2,000? 20,00? 200,0? 2000?). If you will always know how many decimal places you want, use something like yourstring.substring(-2) to take the string apart, then join it back together inserting the comma.

Comment: add comma function: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html  you can modify it's regex to suit your purposes

Comment: @generalhenry: that script makes several assumptions: that you want a decimal point to separate the last two digits, and that you want a comma as a thousands separator - granted, these are reasonable assumptions for `en_US`.

Comment: Agreed, but since it's source, it's easy to make a localized version ^.^

Answer (score 3):

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
"20,00".replace(/,/g,"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expressions are your friend:

```
"20,00".replace(/[^\D]/g, '');
```

This will remove anything that's not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regex way.

```
var result = "20,00".split(',').join('');
```

Comment: Isn't split() also regex-based?

Comment: @Piskvor - Good question. I suppose it depends on how each particular browser implements it. If it was, I'd think that certain characters passed in the string could break the regex. [Here's a test comparing the two.](http://jsperf.com/split-via-regex-vs-string) I honestly assumed that the regex would be slower, but it appears to not always be the case.

Comment: [Here's the same test](http://jsperf.com/split-via-regex-vs-string-no-join) but without the `.join()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your number is a string. Then you could do `parseInt('20.00'.replace(/\./, ''))` or in your case, if you use comma as separator, `parseInt('20.00'.replace(/,/, ''))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have on comma in your string, you don't event need regex:

```
"20,00".replace(',', '');
// gives 2000
```